# In SSIS, can I change the project.param value?

Tags: ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I can see and I can modify the values of the project variables, but my question is ... Can I modify the value of the parameters Project.params or Package Params?  I do not find that option.

[image]
For example, I create a project parameter called StopExecution of type Boolean with its value in False, and when an error occurs in one of my SSIS steps, can I change the value of the Project.param StopExecution to True?, with this functionality in my other package called Package2.dtsx, before starting its execution when I finish my first package called Package1.dtsx (both are executed for a SQL job) Can I validate if my Package2.dtsx has to be executed?

Can you help me? I can do that?

Comment: Do you mean change it programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Project Parameters are read-only; you can specify its value at package start.
You are looking for some global parameter which you can change in child package. File, SQL table or Web service could be such global storage; you write some value to an SQL table and read it later.
There is a [guideline](https://wilberbeast.com/2014/08/15/code-reuse-in-ssis-passing-values-to-and-from-child-packages/) how to use SSIS parent package variables from child package and update parent package variable from child. You can try it, but this scenario relies on variable scope hack.